# Perl cannot open file; from Ploteig script

Tags: perl

I am a total novice when it comes to computer programming and perl, so please forgive me if this question is simple!

I am trying to run a perl script (called ploteig, a component of a free genetics program download, Eigenstrat:[Eigenstrat software](http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/alkes-price/software/)) that works fine until I get to line 96-

```
open (YY, ">$dfile") || die "can't open $dfile\n" ;
```

I am given the error that the file is unable to be opened and the script dies.

Below, I have provided the entire code for you (since honestly, I have no idea what part of the code could be influencing the inability to open the file). The code uses input from a file created previously with Eigenstrat, example of 4 rows, 12 columns:

```
#eigvals:    20.388     7.503     4.033     2.929     2.822     2.726     2.700     2.590     2.451     2.365 
GREY_BI_011_COMSTOCK_11     0.0164      0.0164      0.0382     -0.1283     -0.0658      0.0406      0.0322      0.0105     -0.0851     -0.0625             Case
GREY_BI_014_COMSTOCK_14     0.0191      0.0094      0.0567     -0.0250      0.0804     -0.0531     -0.0165      0.0321      0.1130     -0.0025          Control
GREY_BI_015_COMSTOCK_15     0.0221     -0.0042     -0.0031      0.0091      0.1448      0.0351      0.0430      0.0359      0.0049      0.0791          Control
```

(rows represent individual sample pca scores, columns specific pcas. First column sample names, last column case or control status)

Additionally, I call the code as follows:

```
perl ploteig –i combogreyout.pca.evec –p Case:Control –s Out –c 1:2 –x –o utploteig.xtxt –k
```

I am really unsure where to go from here. I tried changing the file permissions and ensuring it was in the working directory, but it wouldn’t allow me to change permissions and everything pointed to being in the correct directory. However, I am unsure if either of these are the real problem.

I would very much appreciate any help anyone can give me!
Thank you SO much!

```
> #!/usr/bin/perl  -w 

### ploteig -i eigfile -p pops -c a:b [-t title] [-s stem] [-o outfile] [-x] [-k]  [-y] 
[-z sep]   [-f fixgreen]
use Getopt::Std ;
use File::Basename ;

## pops : separated  -x = make postscript and pdf  -z use another separator
##  -k keep intermediate files
## NEW if pops is a file names are read one per line

getopts('i:o:p:c:s:d:z:t:xkyf',\%opts) ;
$postscmode = $opts{"x"} ;
$oldkeystyle =  $opts{"y"} ;
$kflag = $opts{"k"} ;
$keepflag = 1 if ($kflag) ;
$keepflag = 1 unless ($postscmode) ;
$dofixgreen = ( exists $opts{"f"} ? $opts{"f"} : 0 );

$zsep = ":" ;
if (defined $opts{"z"}) {
 $zsep = $opts{"z"} ;
 $zsep = "\+" if ($zsep eq "+") ;
}

$title = "" ;
if (defined $opts{"t"}) {
 $title = $opts{"t"} ;
}
if (defined $opts{"i"}) {
 $infile = $opts{"i"} ;
}
else {
 usage() ;
 exit 0 ;
}
open (FF, $infile) || die "can't open $infile\n" ;
@L = (<FF>) ;
chomp @L ;
$nf = 0 ;
foreach $line (@L) { 
 next if ($line =~ /\#/) ;
 @Z = split " ", $line ;
 $x = @Z ;
 $nf = $x if ($nf < $x) ;
}
printf "## number of fields: %d\n", $nf ;
$popcol = $nf-1 ;


if (defined $opts{"p"}) {
 $pops = $opts{"p"} ;
}
else {
 die "p parameter compulsory\n" ;
}

$popsname = setpops ($pops) ;
print "$popsname\n" ;

$c1 = 1; $c2 =2 ;
if (defined $opts{"c"}) {
 $cols = $opts{"c"} ;
 ($c1, $c2) = split ":", $cols ;
 die "bad c param: $cols\n" unless (defined $cols) ;
}

$stem = "$infile.$c1:$c2" ;
if (defined $opts{"s"}) {
 $stem = $opts{"s"} ;
}
$gnfile = "$stem.$popsname.xtxt" ;

if (defined $opts{"o"}) {
 $gnfile = $opts{"o"} ;
}


@T = () ; ## trash 
open (GG, ">$gnfile") || die "can't open $gnfile\n" ;
print GG "## " unless ($postscmode) ;
print GG "set terminal postscript color\n" ;
print GG "set title  \"$title\" \n" ; 
print GG "set key outside\n" unless ($oldkeystyle) ; 
print GG "set xlabel  \"eigenvector $c1\" \n" ; 
print GG "set ylabel  \"eigenvector $c2\" \n" ; 
print GG "plot " ;
$np = @P ;
$lastpop = $P[$np-1] ;
$d1 = $c1+1 ;
$d2 = $c2+1 ;
foreach $pop (@P)  { 
 $dfile = "$stem:$pop" ;
 push @T, $dfile ;
 print GG " \"$dfile\" using $d1:$d2 title \"$pop\" " ;
 print GG ", \\\n" unless ($pop eq $lastpop) ;
  chomp $dfile;
 open (YY, ">$dfile") || die "can't open $dfile\n" ;
 foreach $line (@L) {
  next if ($line =~ /\#/) ;
  @Z = split " ", $line ;
  next unless (defined $Z[$popcol]) ;
  next unless ($Z[$popcol] eq $pop) ;
  print YY "$line\n" ;
 }
 close YY ;
}
print GG "\n" ;
print GG "## "  if ($postscmode) ;
print GG "pause 9999\n"  ;
close GG ;

if ($postscmode) { 
$psfile = "$stem.ps" ;

 if ($gnfile =~ /xtxt/) { 
  $psfile = $gnfile ;
  $psfile  =~ s/xtxt/ps/ ;
 }
system "gnuplot < $gnfile > $psfile" ;
if ( $dofixgreen )  {
  system "fixgreen  $psfile" ;
}
system "ps2pdf  $psfile " ;
}
unlink (@T) unless $keepflag ;

sub usage { 

print "ploteig -i eigfile -p pops -c a:b [-t title] [-s stem] [-o outfile] [-x] [-k]\n" ;  
print "-i eigfile     input file first col indiv-id last col population\n" ;
print "## as output by smartpca in outputvecs \n" ;
print "-c a:b         a, b columns to plot.  1:2 would be common and leading 2 eigenvectors\n" ;
print "-p pops        Populations to plot.  : delimited.   eg  -p Bantu:San:French\n" ;
print "## pops can also be a filename.  List populations 1 per line\n" ;
print "[-s stem]      stem will start various output files\n"  ;
print "[-o ofile]     ofile will be gnuplot control file.  Should have xtxt suffix\n"; 
print "[-x]           make ps and pdf files\n" ; 
print "[-k]           keep various intermediate files although  -x set\n" ;
print "## necessary if .xtxt file is to be hand edited\n" ;
print "[-y]           put key at top right inside box (old mode)\n" ;
print "[-t]           title (legend)\n" ;
print "[-f]           fix green and yellow colors\n";

print "The xtxt file is a gnuplot file and can be easily hand edited.  Intermediate files
needed if you want to make your own plot\n" ;

}
sub setpops {      
 my ($pops) = @_  ; 
 local (@a, $d, $b, $e) ; 

 if (-e $pops) {  
  open (FF1, $pops) || die "can't open $pops\n" ;
  @P = () ;
  foreach $line (<FF1>) { 
  ($a) = split " ", $line ;
  next unless (defined $a) ;
  next if ($a =~ /\#/) ;
  push  @P, $a ;
  }
  $out = join ":", @P ; 
  print "## pops: $out\n" ;
  ($b, $d , $e) = fileparse($pops) ;
  return $b ;
 }
 @P = split $zsep, $pops ;
 return $pops ;

}
```

Comment: To make it clearer for you what @toolic said, change that line to: `open (YY, ">$dfile") || die "can't open $dfile: $!\n" ;` and you'll get some hint on why the file can't be opened.

Comment: Thank you toolic and @leeft. The result I get when I changed the line to open (YY, ">$dfile") || die "can't open $dfile: $!\n" ; is the error message "No such file or directory". I did try using the -d and -e flags for the $dfile, and both flags gave me a true response (I believe this means the file is in the directory and the file exists). However, I cannot find the file in the directory I am running the script from. Thank you very much!

Comment: FWIW, the script is somewhat of a dialect of write-only perl. Share a directory listing and the full output of the script, and maybe we can get somewhere further. One thing it seems to do is get the filename out of an input file.

Comment: Hi @Leeft, thank you again for responding! I am uncertain how to share a directory listing. Yes, this does take the $dfile name from an input file (and also the -s flag when calling the script). I pasted an example of the contents of the input file in my question (#eigvals) and the name is listed in the -i flag. The output I get from the current script is a .xtxt file that contains exactly the following: set terminal postscript color
set title  "" 
set key outside
set xlabel  "eigenvector 1" 
set ylabel  "eigenvector 2" 
plot  "Out:Case" using 2:3 title "Case" , \

Comment: The problem might be your permissions to read the file.
Try an 'ls -l' and check if you got the permissions to read it.

Comment: Thank you @ProfGhost! It turns out this is correct! I was using virtual box and Ubuntu to run the program through a shared directory on my desktop. So, i was getting results that said I had read/write permissions, but it was to the desktop directory not from the Ubuntu side of the directory. I made those changes and now it works just fine! Thank you everyone for your help!